# Download files opened in an inner window with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to download files on https://aplicaciones007.jne.gob.pe/srop_publico/Consulta/PadronAfiliado#
The problem I am facing is when I click on some of the entries, for instance the first one 'ACCION POPULAR', a new inner window pops up which I cannot interact with Selenium. Here are the lines to click on one of the 6 files opened after clicking on 'ACCION POPULAR'. However, it doesn't click on the files and I basically tried all possible XPATHS for the files.

```
for i in range(1,7):
                file_path = '//*[@id="MiVentanaContenido"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td'
                file = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, file_path)
                print(file.text)
                file.click()
```

Comment: It looks like some of these windows are pdfs?

Comment: Yeah, is this even an issue? I had downloaded pdf files with Options before but couldn't get around this one

Comment: Can you minify your example, to a specific case. I am not 100% sure where the exact problem is.

Comment: I basically want to download all the files on the website. The problem is I cannot click on the file names on the inner window pop up after clicking on some rows. For instance, I can click on 'ACCION POPULAR' with Selenium, but I cannot go further and click on one of 6 new elements after that

Comment: That is great, now you can post code to tackle that exact problem, without two giant loops.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason it is not clicking on the `6 links` after `clicking on ACCION POPULAR` is because we are specifying to click on the table data row `//*[@id="MiVentanaContenido"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td` instead of the `anchor link present in the row` i.e  `//*[@id="MiVentanaContenido"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/a`

Your solution would look like

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  
driver.get('https://aplicaciones007.jne.gob.pe/srop_publico/Consulta/PadronAfiliado#') 
driver.maximize_window()
wait =WebDriverWait(driver, 5) 
wait.until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='ACCION POPULAR']"))
).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table table-striped table-bordered']/descendant::a")))
list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table table-striped table-bordered']/descendant::a") 
for file in list:
 print(file.text)
 file.click()
```

Comment: Hi @Nuri Taş can you check the above solution

Comment: Thank you, that's got it. I'm not sure why clicking on the row raises an error though.

Comment: I wonder how you came up with this answer given the code in the question ...

Comment: Hi @dosas when i tried the above code in the question the click was not trigger on the anchor link updated the path to anchor link for the click to happen